# How to create a multi dimensional array or list and access it in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I wanted to store phone number and full-name in an array.
How can I do that in PHP, and then how can I reference the full-name if I know the phone number

```
1-222-222-2222, John Smith
1-333-333-3333, Frank Jones
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write something simpler like this..

```
foreach(explode(PHP_EOL,$str) as $v)
{
    $new_arr[]=explode(',',$v);
}
```

<kbd>[Demonstration](https://eval.in/149443)</kbd>

You can refer like this..

```
$phone = '1-333-333-3333';
foreach($new_arr as $k=>$arr)
{
    if(in_array($phone,$arr))
    {
        echo $arr[1]; //"prints" Frank Jones
        break;
    }
}
```